# Printing a Rectangle in Java with limits and IF statement that isn't working

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that takes user input and makes a rectangle. The user input to numbers for length and width and another symbol or character to fill in the rectangle. That all works fine.  My code works for creating a rectangle of any size but I need limit If the no of rows or cols is less than or equal to zero or more than 50 it needs to print out "error in input".

This is the code I have and I am currently trying to define it with if statement and it keeps print the state "error in input and the rectangle. Any help would be appreciated or another method to achieve the same thing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rectangle
  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
  {
 int length;
 int width;
 String symbol;
 char symbolz;
 int xLength;
 int yWidth;



 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);         
 while(input.hasNext()){
    {  width = input.nextInt();
       length = input.nextInt();
       symbol = input.next();
       symbolz = symbol.charAt(0);


       if (length<=0||length>50||width<=0||width>50){
       }
        System.out.print("error in input");{

       {for (yWidth = 1; yWidth <= width; yWidth++){
        for (xLength = 1; xLength <= length; xLength++) {
            System.out.print(symbolz);
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
    }
    for(yWidth = 1; yWidth >= width; yWidth--){
        for (xLength = 1; xLength >= length; xLength--){
            System.out.print(symbolz);
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Edited: switched to if statement but still am having trouble because it keeps inserting "error in user input" in all things typed and also prints the rectangle when it isn't supposed to.

So far I have tried to get the If statement to work and it keeps doing the same thing where it keeps print "error in user input" on inputs that are out side the range but it also prints the rectangle after which it shouldn't do. Any guidance?

Answer (score 0):

The construct is called a do-while, and the general format is:

```
do {
    // statements
} while (condition);
```

Your do loop is missing the `while (condition)` which indicates when the loop should stop.

It's essentially a while loop, with the difference being that with do-while, condition is tested at the end of the loop, where with a while loop, it's tested at the start, so a do-while will always execute the loop at least once.

Comment: Is this the best way to do it or should I maybe use a If statement ?

Comment: Depends on how you want to do it.  You need to read user input and validate.  If invalid, print message and prompt again.  If valid, process, and depending on your app, prompt again.  Generally, only want to print message once per input

Comment: just switched to if statement and now it is inserts "error in input" in all inputs and also prints the rectangle no matter what.

Comment: the if statement validating length and width has a semicolon before the { so the if statement has a null then statement, so the print is always being done.

Comment: I took out the semicolon and it is still doing the same thing as in putting "error in user input" always in. I'm sorry about the questions I am new to this.

Comment: I ran it and it seemed to behave correctly, giving valid inputs for  length and width it printed the matrix, giving invalid input(s), it printed message once, then went back to read more.  You can either run it in a debugger and step through and see what's going on, or add println after each input.next call and see what was read in.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with a if and continue statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rectangle
 {
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 int length;
 int width;
 String symbol;
 char symbolz;
 int xLength;
 int yWidth;



 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 while(input.hasNext()){
    {  width = input.nextInt();
       length = input.nextInt();
       symbol = input.next();
       symbolz = symbol.charAt(0);
       if (length<=0||length>50||width<=0||width>50){
       System.out.print("error in input");
       System.out.println();
       continue;}
   {
       for (yWidth = 1; yWidth <= width; yWidth++){
            for (xLength = 1; xLength <= length; xLength++) {
                System.out.print(symbolz);

    }

    System.out.println(" ");
}
for(yWidth = 1; yWidth >= width; yWidth--){
    for (xLength = 1; xLength >= length; xLength--){
         System.out.print(symbolz);
    }

    System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Error is here :

```
  if (length<=0||length>50||width<=0||width>50){
       }    // --> Error: if input outside range then we have to use continue or exit.
        System.out.print("error in input");{   // Message must be in previous if
```

use This:

```
  if((length<=0 || length >50) || (width<=0 || width>50))
       {
         System.out.println("Error in input");
       }
```

Hope this may solve your problem.